# Link not working in notFound component nextjs 13.4

Tags: javascript, next.js

I created a `not-found.tsx` component in my app directory in nextjs 13.4 which works fine when I enter wrong route as seen below:

```js
import Link from 'next/link'

function NotFound() {
  
  return (
    <section>
      
      404, page not found
      <br/>
      <Link href="/">Back to HomePage</Link>

    </section>
  )
}

export default NotFound
```

But when I click the link to go back to the homepage, I still get the 404 page not found page.

I tried using the `useRouter` to navigate away but got the same problem. I notice the issue is as a result of not-found being in the app directory with the homepage

[image: project structure]

So how do I navigate from the not found page to the home page?

Comment: if you have metadata in your home page, can u remove and test it again

Comment: This looks like a bug in nextjs 13.4.1. Facing same issue but didn't find anything online. As a workaround, I have implemented my own solution in middleware to redirect to a custom "notfound" route if the route is invalid.

Comment: ok, i will try creating a middleware to redirect to the not found

Comment: I faced the same problem. It looks like a bug. I changed it for a "standard" anchor tag, to do a "normal" navigation, and hopefully I will update it to "Link" when it's fixed.

Comment: it has actually been fixed, just update your project to the latest nextjs version,  npm install next@latest react@latest react-dom@latest. and everything should work fine

Comment: It's good practice to ***upvote***  an answer as well as accept it if it was useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this was a bug in nextjs 13.4 and it has been fixed, just install the latest version of next  npm install next@latest react@latest react-dom@latest. and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In nextjs you have to create a file called 404.js or 404.tsx in the pages directory for 404 to works

like this :

this is the pages directory

[image]

inside it create a file called 404.js or 404.tsx

[image]

and inside 404.js write your code :

```
import Link from "next/link"

function PageNotFound(){
  return (
    <section>
      <h1>PAGE NOT FOUND </h1>
      <Link href="/"> BACK TO HOME PAGE</Link>
    </section>
 )
}

export default PageNotFound
```

I just tried it and it works fine a get me back to the home page

hope i helped

Comment: im using nextjs 13.4 app directory